# Flutter Application Stuck at Splashscreen

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

> Hi People... I'm having Difficulties with SplashScreen on Flutter... My app installs and opens, but it gets stuck with the splash screen logo... It doesn't go further... I provide you my codes, need help...
>
> AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.manish.hotel">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

   <application
    android:name=".Application"
    android:label="Hotel App"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">

    
    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@mipmap/ic_notification" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <!-- This keeps the window background of the activity showing
             until Flutter renders its first frame. It can be removed if
             there is no splash screen (such as the default splash screen
             defined in @style/LaunchTheme). -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame"
            android:value="true" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

SplashScreen.dart

```
        import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';
import 'package:mvc_pattern/mvc_pattern.dart';
import 'package:manish_hotel_ui/generated/i18n.dart';
import 'package:manish_hotel_ui/src/controllers/controller.dart';
import 'package:manish_hotel_ui/src/repository/user_repository.dart';

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return SplashScreenState();
  }
}

class SplashScreenState extends StateMVC<SplashScreen> {
  Controller _con;

  SplashScreenState() : super(Controller()) {
    _con = controller;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadData();
  }

  Future<Timer> loadData() async {
    return new Timer(Duration(seconds: 5), onDoneLoading);
  }

  onDoneLoading() async {
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      if (currentUser.apiToken == null) {
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/login');
      } else {
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/pages', arguments: 2);
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _con.scaffoldKey,
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Icon(
                Icons.hotel_menu,
                size: 90,
                color: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
              ),
              Text(
                S.of(context).hotel,
                style: Theme.of(context)
                    .textTheme
                    .display1
                    .merge(TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor)),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 50),
              CircularProgressIndicator(
                valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

launch_background

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
     <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
    </item> 
</layer-list>
```

Need help guys, its been 2 months trying to figure it out, still cant solve...

Comment: I also had the same problem, just restarting the app may solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but i tried no progress...

Comment: Any updates on this? Did you manage to solve the problem? How?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you register a `PostFrameCallback` 5 seconds after launch, so the widget is already built and the callback is never executed. Just try removing this :

```
SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
 // Extract the code inside
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I tried but still no progress...